# Is it possible to get a resolution of tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width`.

But it does not provide me proper resolutions of tablet.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your screen size/resolution with `window.devicePixelRatio`:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var width = window.screen.width * ratio;
var height = window.screen.height * ratio;
```

Then to detect if it is an Asus Nexus 7, you will have to use an external API or extension like `ua-parser.js`, available on GitHub at https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js. Here is what I came up with using their library:

```
var parser = new UAParser();
var result = parser.getResult();
if (result.device.vendor == "Asus" && result.device.model == "Nexus 7" && result.device.type == "tablet")
    // Code to redirect to mobile version website
```

Combining the two:

```
<script src="ua-parser.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
   var width = window.screen.width * ratio;
   var height = window.screen.height * ratio;
   var parser = new UAParser();
   var result = parser.getResult();
   if ((width < 700 && height < 900) || (result.device.vendor == "Asus" && result.device.model == "Nexus 7" && result.device.type == "tablet"))
      // Code to redirect to mobile version website
</script>
```

Comment: I am creating a senerio for my web app ,
If a user open my website on tablet (some specific resolution ),
then it must be redirect to my mobile version website otherwise dekstop version.
Now i have to get the resolution for force to redirect on mobile web version.

From this,
I am able to get resolution

var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var width = window.screen.width * ratio;
var height = window.screen.height * ratio;

But i have one more case , if some device reolution value is less then my saved resolution value , then
these also redirect to my mobile version website.

Comment: @ravindersharma I don't know exactly what you're asking, whether it's what the common resolution/screen size is for a normal tablet or how to redirect to your website's version for mobile devices based on the device's resolution/screen size. The screen size of a tablet varies, and I don't know the code behind your mobile version website. Is a simple `if` statement, like maybe `if(width < 720 && height < 1080)`, what you are looking for?

Comment: I want some specific tablets to redirect to the mobile website.
Is it possible?

Comment: @ravindersharma Can you be more precise in what specific tablets you want? Like do they have to be a certain resolution, come from a certain manufacturer, or have a certain operating system like Android or iOS? Be more specific.

Comment: I have two cases,

First case,
Asus Nexus 7 (2012)
Asus Nexus 7 (2013)
to be redirect to mobile version website.

Second case,
I have a minimum resolution value (700 * 900).
All devices that resolution value less then (700 * 900) must also be redirect to mobile version site.

Comment: Is the extension you mentioned above returns all devices detail ?

Comment: @ravindersharma Yes. You can also get the browser, engine, operating system, and CPU details of the mobile device. See the link I gave you.

Comment: If I have to redirect,
 iPad pro to mobile version website.
Does the extension you mentioned returns the proper model name?

Comment: Seems like it is returning only 
device: {vendor: "Apple", model: "iPad", type: "tablet"}
It is not returning ipad proper model i.e (pro, etc).

Comment: As long as you can detect if the device is Asus Nexus 7 like you said, you should be good to go. I'm not sure how specific the developers of this API got when it came to model names, but for some, like iPad, they may not get too specific on each vendor.

Comment: Can I do by saving the device pixel in the database and redirect by matching the resolution?

Comment: @ravindersharma I'm not too sure what you're asking. What would you need a database for?